# Add visible window titles to combobox MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox

I want to add visible window titles to a combobox. Here is my source:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) 
{
     TCHAR buff[255];
     CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_PROCESS);
     if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) 
     {
         GetWindowText(hWnd, buff, 254);
         pComboBox->AddString(buff);
     }
     return TRUE;
}

void CFindProcess::OnDropdownComboProcess()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
}
```

but I get error:

```
error C2660: 'GetDlgItem' : function does not take 1 arguments  60
```

How I can correctly add titles to combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC objects are thread-sensitive, `GetDlgItem` works well in the thread that created the object, probably the main UI thread. Function `EnumWindows` probably creates a worker thread to access the callback function, and that is why `GetDlgItem` failed to get a valid handle of the combobox.

To access the combobox properly in another thread, you have to use the static function: `CWnd::FromHandle` with the raw handle of the combobox object as follows:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) 
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) 
    {   TCHAR szBuffer[255];
        INT nLength = GetWindowText(hWnd, szBuffer, 254);
        if (nLength>0)
        {   // only add windows that has a caption
            CComboBox *pComboBox = (CComboBox*)CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)lParam);
            pComboBox->AddString(szBuffer);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// call EnumWindows --------------------
CComboBox *pComboBox = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1);
// passing the raw handle of the combobox as parameter
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)pComboBox->m_hWnd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `GetDlgItem` has two parameters, and the first is *a handle to the dialog box that contains the control.*

So it expects a `HWND` parameter of the dialog that contains this control, I would presume that will be the `HWND` you pass as a parameter to your function.

```
 CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_COMBO_PROCESS);
                                                 ^^^^ added parameter
```

If you look at [`EnumWindows` in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see you have to pass a callback and it has a `HWND` parameter, if you look at what this parameter is for it says:

> A handle to a top-level window.

This is exactly what you have to pass to `GetDlgItem`.

Also, you should check the return value of `GetWindowText` as this returns the number of characters written to the `buff` you passed it.

```
     int ret = GetWindowText(hWnd, buff, 254);
     if (ret > 0) pComboBox->AddString(buff); // only add non-empty strings.
```

Comment: True that helped but still something wrong. I get program crash OnDropdownComboProcess(). debuging says: `_AFXWIN_INLINE int CComboBox::AddString(LPCTSTR lpszString)
 { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpszString); }` i'm new in MFC I want understand how its works...

Comment: Please call `GetLastError` to get a message as to what the error is?

Comment: `First-chance exception at 0x012230B4 in L2Hamster.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
Unhandled exception at 0x012230B4 in L2Hamster.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.`

Comment: That's a null pointer exception, somewhere you're trying to read from uninitialized memory.

Comment: hmm... any idea how I can put all running programs title names to combobox?

Comment: You're on the right path, afaik, but you have to debug your program to find out where the bug is.  Step through it and see where it throws that access violation in **your code**.

Comment: @Klasik what's happening in your code? Have you looked at the values of your variables at the time of the error? What are they? Are they correct? Etc...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what user @mfc has provided, I would not do UI update from a different thread. I believe `EnumWindows` does **not** create thread for enumeration. It would call the callbacks within the call-stack of current thread.

This, in turn, means that UI may freeze for a while. Thus, it is recommended to create a thread for enumeration. More over, I would not directly update UI from different thread. May be a `vector` of string, or a `PostMessage` (on each iteration) I would have used.

It is true that `EnumWindows` may perform quite fast. But when you move to enumerate other (kernel) objects like file, printers, users etc - the UI is definitely going to freeze. So, better practice writing multithreaded code. Initially writing MT-code would be a pain, but later you'd love it, appreciate it, and cannot live without it.